# how would I reimplement this code to be recursive?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [creating a recursive method for Palindrome In java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367260/creating-a-recursive-method-for-palindrome-in-java)

This is my code that I have written.

```
public boolean checkPalindrome(string word){

for(int i=0 ; i < word.length()/2;i++)
{
  if(word.charAt(i) ! = word.charAt(word.length()-1-i))

      return false;
}

return true;
}
```

The purpose of this method to check if a given string is a palindrome.

Comment: This is homework, right? Please edit to add a "homework" tag.

Comment: call the method number of times you are calling the for loop as the an example posted in the question asked by you about recursion

Comment: You posted 4 questions in the last hour. Looks like you want to rewrite your code without doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: change function signature to `boolean checkPalindrome(String word, int index);`

Answer (score 1):

If you had a function that could check whether a sub-string of your word is a palindrome, would that help you check whether your main word was also a palindrome?