# Recursive Palindrome, Java

Tags: java

I am using recursion to find out whether a string is a palindrome, while ignoring spaces and non letter characters. However, each space causes the string to be split and tested separately. Here is my code.

```
public class RecursivePalindrome
{
RecursivePalindrome()
{
}
public boolean checkPalindrome(String y)
{
    String s = y;
    String removed = s.replaceAll("\\W", "");
    removed = removed.toLowerCase();
    return isPalindrome(removed);

}

public boolean isPalindrome(String y)
{
    if ( y.length() < 2 )
      return true;
    char firstChar = y.charAt(0);
    char lastChar = y.charAt(y.length() - 1);

    if(firstChar != lastChar)
      return false;
    else
      return checkPalindrome(y.substring(1, y.length()-1));
}
```

}

This is the tester class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RecursivePalindromeTester
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    RecursivePalindrome aMethod = new RecursivePalindrome();
    int z = 0;
    while (z < 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a word or phrase.(Entering q will stop the program)");
        String n = in.next();
        if(n.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
        {
        System.out.println("End of Program");
        z++;
       }
       else{
        if (aMethod.checkPalindrome(n))
        {
          System.out.println(n + " is a palindrome");

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(n + " is not a palindrome");
        }}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you give an example of an input that doesn't give the expected output?

Comment: Recursion means: calling itself. Even though your isPalindrome calls checkPalindrome, which then again calls isPalindrome, this isn't really recursion. In order for it to be recursion, isPalindrome should call isPalindrome. checkPalindrome shouldn't exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a recursive method for Palindrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367260/creating-a-recursive-method-for-palindrome)

Comment: Thanks for the help. These are the changes I made.                                  return checkPalindrome(y.substring(1, y.length()-1));    to is Palindrome             in.next(); to in.nextLine();  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scanner#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), as per javadoc, *Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner* i.e. a word (breaks on `Space`).

[Scanner#nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) instead *Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped* meaning that gets all the line written (in your case until `Enter` is pressed).

Change `in.next()` to `in.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `RecursivePalindromeTester`. The scanner you are using breaks on whitespace. You can change it to break on newline instead:

```
in.useDelimiter(new Pattern("\n");
```