# Efficient way to get palindrome using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to get palindrome using recursion like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367260/creating-a-recursive-method-for-palindrome), but I found that very costly because It's create new string when I use `substring()` method, like in my code:

```
 public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    if (s.length() <= 1)
        return true;
    else if (s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(s.length() - 1))
        return false;
    else return isPalindrome(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1));
}
```

Is there an alternative way to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the full original `String` and just the indexes to it, it'll be essentially the same thing except without creating so many objects.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s, int start, int end) {
    if ((end-start) <= 1)
        return true;
    else if (s.charAt(start) != s.charAt(end))
        return false;
    else return isPalindrome(s, start+1, end-1);
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    return isPalindrome(s, 0, s.length()-1);
}
```

The original code was more efficient back when `substring()` shared the internal `char[]` of the `String`, but [that changed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893655/string-substring-making-a-copy-of-the-underlying-char-value) Even then this would've been a better option, since the `String` objects were still created even though the internal `char[]` was shared.